# Running React while rebooting Ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu

Whenever I run the React app, I have to run manually by typing `yarn build & yarn start`. If I reboot the server, I should re-run manually again. Is there a better way of automatically running the web engine?

My idea is writing the command in `/etc/rc.local` file. But I am not sure if this is proper or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pm2](https://pm2.io/runtime/): Advanced, production process manager for Node.js.

First install pm2 with

```
npm install --global pm2
```

and then you can start your app by

```
cd /path/to/app
pm2 start npm -- start
```

The pm2 will manage your React service.

If you want to auto run this on boot:

```
pm2 save        # Save your process.
pm2 startup     # Install auto start script.
```

Further information, you can find pm2 docs [here](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/overview/).